# setParameter not replacing wildcard?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been wasting quite a bit of time trying to figure out why I cannot use the setParameter method on Doctrine Query objects in Symfony 2.

I created a custom repository class, where I want to add a few custom search methods / finders.

I have tried so many different combinations of building DQL and in each case it doesn't replace the wildcards I specify. I'm hoping it's something obvious that I missed, but I'm a bit confused non the less.

```
// Repository class

namespace Acme\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PurchaseOrderRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllFiltered($sortType = 'id', $sort = 'ASC', $offset = 1, $limit = 30)
    {
        //Variation 1
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
                      SELECT po FROM AcmePurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder po
                      WHERE po.id = ?1'
        );
        $query->setParameter(1, 1);

        return $query->getDql();    

        // Yields: SELECT po FROM AcmePurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder po WHERE po.id = ?1

        //Variation 2
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
                      SELECT po FROM AcmePurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder po
                      WHERE po.id = :value'
        );

        $query->setParameter('value', 1);

        return $query->getDql();
        // Yields: SELECT po FROM AcmePurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder po WHERE po.id = :value
    }
}
```

I started off using the QueryBuilder, but this also ended up with the same problem, I could not get parameters to save! This is really so weird and frustrating.

I'm using Symfony 2.1.5-DEV

Comment: +1 for well explained and detailed question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how prepared statements work - `getDQL()` returns the prepared statement. To get the parameters you need to do

```
$query->getParameters();
```

Doctrine passes both the prepared statement and the parameters for execution it doesn't send a query.